# Cordova (android) deploy issues

Tags: android, cordova, deployment

I am a newbie on using cordova (or phonegap), I was doing some demo projects and found a strange problem on deploying the projects on my android phone (Nexus 5)

when I run: "cordova run android"
everything seems fine and the app is installed on my phone as well, however, I found that after successfully installing the app, the EARLIER installed app /demos (created by cordova as well) was removed!!!

I was wondering if it was related to any platform dependent settings on android? It seems that no matter what the built apk's name was, it would eventually uninstall the already installed cordova apps; by then the new cordova app would be installed (sort of like file copying and the new file would overwrite the existing file -- assume same file name)

Anybody got clues on this???

Jason

Comment: when you create a cordova application you specify a package name when you run `cordova create`. If you are copy/pasting your project code, it will have the same package name for all the project and the deployment process will overwrite the application each time

Comment: thx~ I tried your way and seems working~